# What is possible reason for messages stuck in Dispatched Queue of ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a Spring application that consumes messages from ActiveMQ. The app runs fine initially. However, after a couple of days it stops consuming messages. The ActiveMQ Web Console shows that 1 enqueued, 0 dequeued, 1 dispatched, 1 is in Dispatched Queue.

If I restart the app the messages in Dispatched Queue get consumed and new messages are consumed as expected.

If I didn't take any action the after another one or two days the message in Dispatched Queue is eventually consumed. But the new messages go to Dispatched Queue again.

Following is the configuration:

```xml
    <bean id="baseConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory"></bean>

    <bean id="singleConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="baseConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="requestListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
      <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5"/>
      <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
      <property name="idleTaskExecutionLimit" value="5"/>
      <property name="maxMessagesPerTask" value="1000"/>
      <property name="receiveTimeout" value="${mq.i94dataentry.receivetimeout}"/>
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="singleConnectionFactory" />
      ...
    </bean>
```

What could be the possible reason for this scenario?

I don't have access to the app box due to security restrictions so I am unable to acquire any [thread dumps](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump). I guess the issue is caused by dynamic scaling of consumers and the value of `maxMessagesPerTask` (prefetch). I have set `concurrentConsumers` equal to `maxConcurrentConsumers` and `maxMessagesPerTask` to `0` and started the app. I will see if the issue occur in next several days.

Comment: I don't have access to the app box due to security restrictions so I am unable to try what you suggested. I guess the issue is caused by dynamic scaling of consumers and the value of maxMessagesPerTask (prefetch). I have set concurrentConsumers = maxConcurrentConsumers, maxMessagesPerTask = 0, and started the app. I will see if the issue occur in next several days.

Comment: What acknowledgement mode?  1 message dispatched and 0 dequeued means the broker has not received the 'ack' for the message using AUTO_ACK, or the transaction is not committed (SESSION_TRANSACTED ackMode)

Comment: The ack mode is AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE. After some msgs got stuck, the listener method onMessage() was not called at all when a new msg had been put into the Q.

Comment: Why is maxMessagesPerTask set to 0?  Try setting it to 1

Comment: It is equivalent to prefetch = 0, which makes consumer pulls message. In this situation, it is impossible for messages to stuck in an inactive consumer.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ, Spring, etc?

Comment: ActiveMQ 5.16.5, springframework 5.32.4, java8

Comment: It has been 5 days passed since I set prefetch to 0. No stuck messages occur.